# Why are some errors silent?

Tags: compiler-errors, silent

I have a relatively simple question, but I imagine that may not be the case of the answer. To put it shortly: Why are some errors silent ?

I understand that throwing an error happens when pretty much anything unexpected (from the POV of the program) happens. Which leads me to think that when this happens, an error message is supposed to provide as much info as possible about why and/or how the error happened. So it seems paradoxical to me that some would be silenced.

I assume this applies to pretty much any language and would just like to know when and where silencing an error is useful and why.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silent errors are errors of which the user is not notified, either because the error is not detected or because it does not make much sense to notify the user.  Whether an error is detected or a user is notified may depend on various components, like compiler, operating system, hardware, etc..
Among not detected errors may be division by 0, which gives undefined behaviour.
Among errors whose notification may not make sense may be errors that occur during logout/shutdown, or if the user could only be notified long after the error occurred, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ErrorTracker) (search there for silent).

Comment: Super that clarifies it for me, thanks a lot that was quick !